# iOS change color some items

Tags: ios, colors

I've a tableviewcontroller, in which there are few cells with label, textfield, etc.. and I want to change color of only label and textfield.

I tried to use that :

```
[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[[UtilisateurManager getCurrUser] getColor]];
```

It work, but the problem is it's changing colors of my navigation drawer's label, and I don't want that, I only want to change the item's color of my tableviewcontroller.

So i tried that :

```
    for(UIView *v in [self.tableView subviews]) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            [(UILabel *)v setTextColor:[[UtilisateurManager getCurrUser] getColor]];
        }
        else if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
            [(UITextView *)v setTextColor:[[UtilisateurManager getCurrUser] getColor]];
        } etc...
}
```

But it doesn't work... I don't understand how can i update the colors of my tableviewcontroller's item, without touch at my navigation drawer.

Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

```
UITableViewCell *cell = ...;

for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", view);
}
```

Then you should have your subviews, if I unterstood you right.

Comment: mhh, in deed, it's not stupid to do that. Thx, i will try in few munutes.

Comment: ok it works, but, I don't understand why my placeholder change color too ?

Comment: oh no, mistake, my bad :D I forgot to cancel my other test.

Answer (score 0):

Error is that below will make all labels color change(it's like ur making change at parent level so all child created will also change) ...

```
[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[[UtilisateurManager getCurrUser] getColor]];
```

So to achieve what u want u could simply do as follow,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  //Or
  label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];  //Your label and textfield color you could set as per ur need.

  return cell;
}
```